# Escrever o acesso ao membro de uma estrutura com ponteiro em vez do uso do operador "->"

Tags: c, ponteiro, operadores

Como faria para escrever essa atribuição:

```
p1->caracter='B';
```

de outra forma usando `*` ao invés de `->`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você primeiro pega o valor do objeto e depois acessa o membro normalmente:

```
(*p1).caracter = 'B';
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Operator/PointerToMember.c).

Este operador é só uma forma de *derreferenciar* o ponteiro e acessar o membro dele.