# Problema com struct: "Expected expression before"

Tags: c, struct

O seguinte problema

> expected expression before 'eqp'

na linha da função 'dados' onde se lê o valor e não consegui identificar a razão de tal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

typedef struct equipamento{
int codigoequipamento;
int tempoativo;
float potencia;
float consumonomes;
char equipamento[30];
}eqp;
typedef struct equipamento eqp;

void menu(void);
void dados(void);
int main(){

   setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese"); 
   int resp=0;
   do{
       menu();
       scanf ("%d",&resp);
       if(resp == 1){ // Para caso deseje-se cadastrar
        dados();

       }if(resp == 2){// Caso deseje-se consultar oq já foi cadastrado

       }if(resp == 3){
          break;
       }if((resp > 3) || (resp < 1)){
          printf("Valor invalido\n");
       }
       }while (resp != 3);
       return 0;
 }
void menu(void){  //menu
  printf("---------------------------------------\n");
  printf("| Sessão de cadastro de equipamentos  |\n");
  printf("---------------------------------------\n");
  printf("Digite 1 para cadastrar\n");
  printf("Digite 2 para consultar os cadastros\n");
  printf("Digite 3 para sair\n");
}

void dados(void){ // Função para ler dados

  printf("Entre com o codigo do equipamento: ");
  scanf("%d",&eqp.codigoequipamento);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem vários erros aí e tentei corrigir os principais (mantive algumas coisas que eu faria diferente em caso real), mantendo uma organização e nomenclatura diferentes, retirando o que é redundante e desnecessário e trocando para o que é mais adequado.

O erro em foco é que está tentando manipular o tipo e não uma variável. Tem que criar a variável. Eu imagino que queria criar no código principal e passar como parâmetro para usar na função que vai manipulá-lo, então foi o que eu fiz.

Sugiro prestar atenção a cada detalhe do que eu alterei (até espaços em branco), em geral não é por caso, é tudo pensado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

typedef struct {
    int codigo;
    int tempoativo;
    float potencia;
    float consumonomes;
    char nome[31];
} Equipamento;

void menu(void) {
    printf("---------------------------------------\n");
    printf("| Sessão de cadastro de equipamentos  |\n");
    printf("---------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Digite 1 para cadastrar\n");
    printf("Digite 2 para consultar os cadastros\n");
    printf("Digite 3 para sair\n");
}

void dados(Equipamento *equipamento) {
    printf("Entre com o codigo do equipamento: ");
    scanf("%d", &equipamento->codigo);
}

int main() {
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese"); 
   int resp = 0;
   Equipamento equipamento;
   do {
       menu();
       scanf("%d", &resp);
       switch (resp) {
       case 1:
           dados(&equipamento);
           break;
       case 2:
           break;
       }
       if (resp > 3 || resp < 1) printf("Valor invalido\n");
    } while (resp != 3);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/xrP5J8). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/uvgfgmmn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/InstanceMemberAccess.c).

Comment: Na leitura de dados você utilizou o "->",  poderia me informar qual conceito isso envolve? p.s: Ajudou muito, obrigada.

Comment: O '->' é usado sempre que o valor que está na direita for um endereço, e o '&' representa "endereço de"; assim quando se utiliza o '&' antes da variável como foi feito em "&equipamento"  deve se usar o '->' ficando "&equipamento->codigo". @CarolineMarx

Comment: @CarolineMarx https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/325987/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51204/101